# Can not use the open and close tag with EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have installed the EJS package in my nodejs project by doing `npm install --save ejs`, however when I type the tag `<% %>`, my IDE does not highlight the syntax.

[image: A screenshot from my text editor]

I expect the tag's color to change from white to blue.

Instead, the `<` is red and the `%` is white. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Hong, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you be a bit more specific with some of the details here? How did you install the ejs package, where are you typing `<% %>`, is it a compiler or highlighting which shows a syntax error?

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison I installed the package by `npm install --save ejs`. I type `<% %>` in a .ejs file. Normally when you type the tag it will change the color that means it is valid but in my case, it seems to be invalid code.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/2dpAz8D) You can see how the problem was here.

Comment: Which code editor you are using? For example, Visual Studio Code by default don't understand EJS, you need to install a plugin for that

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, by default it doesn't understand EJS, you need to install a plugin for that. Following should do

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support